# importing npm package to client side javascript

Tags: javascript, npm, import, client, cdn

I recently trying to use some client-side github packages, and when trying to use them the developers mentions that the packages are downloadable with npm, which I cant understand due to the fact that those are client side javascript packages.
I saw something with import method which I also don't know.
can someone please explain how npm suppose to be used on client side, or how else am I suppose to use those packages?
an example is html2canvas, I just can't figure out how to actually use this package.
much thanks!

Comment: You should read up on 'ES6 modules'

Answer (score -1):

Usage and installation for html2canvas is described below:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas

In nutshell npm packages usage can be explained so:

1. Install package using npm
2. Import required class/functionality from node_modules
3. Use as in documentation:

   html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
       document.body.appendChild(canvas);
   });

Bundler will attach all required functionality by itself.